# What is a “crypto-portrait”?

Tags: meaning, etymology, nouns

I have frequently seen the word *crypto-portrait* popping up in articles on *Wikipedia* and elsewhere, but I was not able to find a definition for it. Apparently there used to be an article on *Wikipedia* but it has since been removed (there are dead links to it).

Here are some of the places you can see the word used:

- http://thelostdutchman.hubpages.com/hub/The-Van-Eyck-Cryptogram
- http://www.discoverbaroqueart.org/database_item.php?id=monument;BAR;cz;Mon11_F;7;en
- http://www.desipientia.nl/archief.php?nummer=41

Comment: I think this is General Reference - despite the fact that you won't find *crypto-portrait* defined in any standard dictionary. The prefix *crypto-* itself has a pretty straightforward and consistent meaning; when applied to *portrait*, it should be obvious that the portrait has some "hidden" (probably, *subversive*) significance.

Comment: I can't find it in [Wikipedia's deletion log](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Special%3ALog&type=delete&user=&page=Crypto-portrait&year=&month=-1&tagfilter=), so those dead links are probably to an as yet not created page.

Comment: +1 Nice question. @FumbleFingers But that doesn't necessarily tell you _what_ is hidden or if the term even means what it is expected to mean. (To me a pedo-phile is somebody with a foot fetish.)

Comment: @coleopterist: Hmm. Well the only answer here presents Lippi's Salome as a possible example, and that's got 7 upvotes. But I'd bet money that (to the extent *crypto-portrait* is used at all, which isn't much) it would normally include some element of "subversiveness". I think in general, the *crypto-* prefix is strongly associated with concealed subversion (often political). Including a likeness of your mother's face in a painting doesn't seem like an archetypal example to me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Crypto-portrait* is an art history term for a portrait of a person which is not identified as such. For example, the painting below is *Dance of Salome*, 1452–1457, by Fra Filippo Lippi. Some art historians suspect this “Salome” is a crypto-portrait: a likeness of Lippi’s mother.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are six late 19th-century woodcuts by Félix Vallotton featuring musical instruments. From oral tradition, they are known to be crypto-portraits of six well-known musicians of the era. It seems that the instrument is not only associated with a given musician because the man played it, but they are drawn so that there is some physical likeness between the instrument and the musician.